# Vuetify navigation-drawer errors when using v-model with Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the `Vuex` store to hold the variable that will control whether or not the `v-navigation-drawer` component is open/visible. The reason is because I want to know if the nav-drawer is open from some other components and apply classes to some elements conditionally. Some code from my `App.vue`:

```
<v-navigation-drawer app v-model="this.$store.state.showNavDrawer" ...
...
<v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="toggleNavDrawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
...
methods: {
    toggleNavDrawer() {
        this.$store.commit('toggleNavDrawer');
    },
},
```

And in my `main.js` where my Vuex data is defined:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
      showNavDrawer: null,
   },
   mutations: {
      toggleNavDrawer(state) {
         state.showNavDrawer = !state.showNavDrawer;
      },
   },
```

On initial page load, the screen size is respected and the nav-drawer shows/hides the way it should, but the following error shows up on the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this is null"

found in

---> <VNavigationDrawer>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
TypeError: this is null
    callback App.vue:17
    VueJS 4
    isActive VNavigationDrawer.ts:248
    VueJS 7
    confirmTransition vue-router.esm.js:2342
    step vue-router.esm.js:1944
    step vue-router.esm.js:1951
    runQueue vue-router.esm.js:1955
    confirmTransition vue-router.esm.js:2335
    step vue-router.esm.js:1944
    step vue-router.esm.js:1948
    iterator vue-router.esm.js:2322
    resolveAsyncComponents vue-router.esm.js:2105
    iterator vue-router.esm.js:2300
    step vue-router.esm.js:1947
    step vue-router.esm.js:1951
    runQueue vue-router.esm.js:1955
    confirmTransition vue-router.esm.js:2330
    transitionTo vue-router.esm.js:2203
    init vue-router.esm.js:2923
    beforeCreate vue-router.esm.js:1271
    VueJS 4
    <anonymous> main.js:42
    js app.js:1113
    __webpack_require__ app.js:849
    fn app.js:151
    1 app.js:1234
    __webpack_require__ app.js:849
    checkDeferredModules app.js:46
    <anonymous> app.js:925
    <anonymous> app.js:928
```

The first click of the nav-drawer control never does anything. There's no movement of the nav-drawer and there are no errors in the console. Every click after that works and shows/hides the drawer like it should, but there's an error in the console for every click:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this is null"

found in

---> <VNavigationDrawer>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
TypeError: this is null
    callback App.vue:17
    VueJS 4
    isActive VNavigationDrawer.ts:248
    VueJS 10
    toggleNavDrawer main.js:32
    wrappedMutationHandler vuex.esm.js:844
    commitIterator vuex.esm.js:466
    commit vuex.esm.js:465
    _withCommit vuex.esm.js:624
    commit vuex.esm.js:464
    boundCommit vuex.esm.js:409
    toggleNavDrawer App.vue:157
    VueJS 4
    click VBtn.ts:158
    VueJS 33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `v-model` to the vuex.

You need to use the `:value="this.$store.state.showNavDrawer"` prop instead. And then modify it with the `@click` event just the way you're doing it and you should be fine.

NB: If I were you I would give a boolean value straight away to your initial state, I don't see any point in making it null to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using v-show, if that helps anybody.